# How Can I Move a data set already on 1 page to a separate page?

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Alright,
 so in the beginning stages of creating a table, I've included the reference table on the same page as the data it's being compared to. Now that the list grows I need to be able to separate the 2 sets of data onto separate pages.(X,Y, Coordinates on 1, Location boundaries on another) There's already code connecting the info within the table, but I can already see how much of a coding nightmare it will be to "ImportRange" to the existing formula. How can I separate the 2 without having 100 lines of "ImportRange"?

````
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2="",,IF(TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, 
 IF((B2*1>=H$2:H)*(B2*1<=I$2:I)*(C2*1>=J$2:J)*(C2*1<=K$2:K), G$2:G, ))="", 
"out of range", TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, 
 IF((B2*1>=H$2:H)*(B2*1<=I$2:I)*(C2*1>=J$2:J)*(C2*1<=K$2:K), G$2:G, )))))```
````

The reference table recalls Titles in row G and compares within range of H-I and J-K.

Here's a link to the original page "COORD" with ALL of the info...
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OZSDju3hRyGyRfFhHJT2PLQ3DBvcfOAT1ZvNxB-J0DQ/edit?usp=sharing

...and the new page to move the locations to "Locations"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2="",,IF(TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, 
 IF((B2*1>=Locations!D$2:D)*(B2*1<=Locations!E$2:E)*
    (C2*1>=Locations!F$2:F)*(C2*1<=Locations!G$2:G), Locations!C$2:C, ))="", 
 "out of range", TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, 
 IF((B2*1>=Locations!D$2:D)*(B2*1<=Locations!E$2:E)*
    (C2*1>=Locations!F$2:F)*(C2*1<=Locations!G$2:G), Locations!C$2:C, )))))
```